# How to differentiate between first int and second int in a java calculator?

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, user-interface, calculator

I'm making a java calculator using MVC style. I'm just having trouble differentiating between the first number they enter and the second one. I put in a boolean that turns true when plus or minus is entered, and this changes the number string back to "", a blank string. But then when I would go to get it when this boolean was true, the string would already be blank so it's too late. Any advice on how to get the first number and then the second one? This calculator is just using plus and minus. With an equals and clear button. thanks

calc class

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


class Calc extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


    private JTextField numDisplay = new JTextField(10);
    private JButton plusButton = new JButton("+");
    private JButton minusButton = new JButton("-");
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    private JButton equalsButton = new JButton("=");
    private JButton zeroButton = new JButton("0");
    private JButton oneButton = new JButton("1");
    private JButton twoButton = new JButton("2");
    private JButton threeButton = new JButton("3");
    private JButton fourButton = new JButton("4");
    private JButton fiveButton = new JButton("5");
    private JButton sixButton = new JButton("6");
    private JButton sevenButton = new JButton("7");
    private JButton eightButton = new JButton("8");
    private JButton nineButton = new JButton("9");
    private String number = "";
    private boolean trueFalse;   //plus or minus
    private boolean onOff = false;   //false = 1st int, true = 2nd int
    private int total;
    private boolean isEquals = false;   // false = haven't clicked equals button yet,     true they have
    //private String numberText;

    Calc(){
        JPanel calcPanel = new JPanel();

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(400, 600);
        calcPanel.add(numDisplay);
        calcPanel.add(plusButton);
        calcPanel.add(minusButton);
        calcPanel.add(clearButton);
        calcPanel.add(equalsButton);
        calcPanel.add(zeroButton);
        calcPanel.add(oneButton);
        calcPanel.add(twoButton);
        calcPanel.add(threeButton);
        calcPanel.add(fourButton);
        calcPanel.add(fiveButton);
        calcPanel.add(sixButton);
        calcPanel.add(sevenButton);
        calcPanel.add(eightButton);
        calcPanel.add(nineButton);

        this.add(calcPanel);

        plusButton.addActionListener(this);
        minusButton.addActionListener(this);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        equalsButton.addActionListener(this);
        zeroButton.addActionListener(this);
        oneButton.addActionListener(this);
        twoButton.addActionListener(this);
        threeButton.addActionListener(this);
        fourButton.addActionListener(this);
        fiveButton.addActionListener(this);
        sixButton.addActionListener(this);
        sevenButton.addActionListener(this);
        eightButton.addActionListener(this);
        nineButton.addActionListener(this);

    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
        if (event.getSource() instanceof JButton){
            JButton clickedButton = (JButton) event.getSource();
            String buttonText = clickedButton.getText();
            if (clickedButton == zeroButton || clickedButton == oneButton || clickedButton == twoButton || clickedButton == threeButton || clickedButton == fourButton || clickedButton == fiveButton || clickedButton == sixButton || clickedButton == sevenButton || clickedButton == eightButton || clickedButton == nineButton)
            {
                number = number + buttonText;
            }
            if (clickedButton == clearButton){
                number = "";
                onOff = false;
            }
            if (clickedButton == plusButton){
                trueFalse = true;
                onOff = true;
            }
            if (clickedButton == minusButton){
                trueFalse = false;
                onOff = true;
                number = "";
            }
            if (clickedButton == equalsButton){
                isEquals = true;
            }
        }
    }
    public int getNumber(){
        return Integer.parseInt(number);
    }
    public boolean trueFalse(){
        return trueFalse;
    }
    public boolean onOff(){
        return onOff;
    }
    public int total(){
        return total;
    }
    public boolean isEquals(){
        return isEquals;
    }
    public String getNumberString(){
        return number;
    }
}
```

calculations class

```
public class Calculations
{
    private Calc theView;
    private CalculationModel theModel;
    private boolean onOff = theView.onOff();
    private boolean trueFalse = theView.trueFalse();
    private int number1;

    public Calculations(Calc theView, CalculationModel theModel)
    {
        this.theView = theView;
        this.theModel = theModel;
    }

    public void doesometing() {
        if(trueFalse)     
        {
            number1 = theView.getNumber();
        }
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to deal with user input is to push the values entered by the user onto a stack. That way he most recent value is last.

To do a calculation you pop two values off the stack, run the calculation and push the result onto the stack.  The next value entered thn goes on the stack after the last result.

Edit: collecting digits to make a number can be done by appending the digits onto the end of a string and converting the string to a number when a non-digit is pressed. Note that two dots in a row isn't a valid number so you need to deal with that.

Comment: right but they are clicking buttons, not inputing characters themselves. Sorry i should have made that more clear

Comment: The presentation isn't what matters, you will have values and operations.  If the button presses result in digits you need to collect those until a function is pressed and make a number from the button presses.

Comment: So how would I do that? Im not sure how to get the number before it is cleared back to blank

Comment: This is an MVC project, so think about the parts of that pattern.  The display of the buttons and value are view.  The actions taken when buttons are pressed are controller and the input string and stack containing the values is model. Every digit pressed would result in an action that appends to the next input string in the model as well as displaying that string in the view.